# recordRTC cant stop audio stream

Tags: javascript

If anyone can suggest a solution, on how to free audio device after recording.
I save videostream, than use `localStream.stop()` and video recording stops.
Where I should save the audiostream, and any suggestions on stop?

```
var localStream;

record.onclick = function() {
record.disabled = true;
        !window.stream && navigator.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
            video: true
        }, function(stream) {
            localStream = stream;
            ...
        }
        function onstream() {
            preview.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            preview.play();
            preview.muted = true;
            recordAudio = RecordRTC(stream, {                
                // bufferSize: 16384,
                onAudioProcessStarted: function() {
                    if (!isFirefox) {                        
                        recordVideo.startRecording();
                        audioStream = stream;
                    }
                }
            });
            recordVideo = RecordRTC(stream, {
                type: 'video'                
            });
            recordAudio.startRecording();
            stop.disabled = false;
        }
}
```

And I stop it in the callback after fileupload:

```
localStream.stop();
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Update:** I've tried:

```
localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
```

**Update 2:** I'see `audioTrack.enable == true` in all cases I'm trying to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always... the sollution was on top.
I've added two lines to the stop click handler.

```
window.stream = undefined;
preview.muted = false;
```

Hope this will help someone.